# Displaying Transparent iFrame on top of an Applet

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, applet, transparency

I wanted to display a transparent iFrame on top of the applet.

However when I use `allowtransparency="true"` and `background-color:transparent`, It shows the background of the html under which applet is embedded. It doesn't show the background applet as such.

Is there a way by which we can display a transparent IFrame on top of an applet and the transparent region of the iFrame shows the background applet.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're not using this for black hat purposes...

try changing the iframe's z-index to underneath the whole page, so transparent or not it won't show...  or display: none.. lot's of ways to do this

Comment: changing the z index or changing the display is also not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know, but it may help you...

```
<html>
 <body bgcolor="black" background="http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif">
  <iframe width="300"
          height="300"
          name="Frame1"
          src="insideIframe.html"
          frameborder="0"
          allowtransparency="true"
          style="background-color:transparent; color:red; filter: alpha(opacity=20) border:5 solid #000000;">
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>

Here is the src for frame.html:

<html>
 <style type="text/css">
   body {
      filter: alpha(opacity=80, style=0);background-color: #FFFFFF; -moz-opacity:0.8;
   }
 </style>
   <body>
      Transparent??? 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This issue comes with an applet. It works independently with htmls.